# How to make additional server adapters visible?

Tags: java, eclipse, webserver, adapter

I have Eclipse EE Indigo installed, when I first checked "new server wizard" I saw such servers as JBoss, Tomcat. However since I am interested in Jetty or Glassfish I installed extra adapters for those (via "download additional server adapters" in Eclipse).

I restarted Eclipse and the list didn't change -- still JBoss, Tomcat and other old stuff. On the other hand I don't see Jetty and GF in "download additional..." window.

As desperate try I installed Jetty WTP, restart, no change.

**How to make newly installed adapters visible?** After all I would like to use those servers (Jetty or GF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try installing them as a new software install: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty_WTP_Plugin/Jetty_WTP_Install

I installed jetty adapter like this and it is visible in eclipse servers now.

Comment: As I said, I did it too. However maybe server adapter prevents it (WTP) to show up -- so far I don't know how to uninstall server adapter.

Comment: I doubt it, I can install the adapter, the server is not shown.

Comment: Yes, I can, but I cannot see any server adapters in the list of installed software.

Comment: I removed all things related to Eclipse and Eclipse itself. Then I installed it again, this time with Jetty as first software installed (with the above link), and now it is finally visible.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes starting eclipse with -clean options helps after installing new plugins.